# Find how long my methods take to execute

Tags: objective-c, profiling

How can I find out which of my methods take the most time to execute in my iPad application?

Comment: Ask a different question: How can I tell how to speed up my code? Then answer it [*this way*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

Answer (score 1):

Put an `NSLog`at the beginning of the method and one at the end

the console shows the exact time for the `NSLog` so thats how you can determine which takes log time

Example:

```
-(void)buttonsTag{
  NSLog(@"Beginning of buttonsTag Method");
  btn1.tag  =1;
  btn2.tag  =2;
  btn3.tag  =3;
  btn4.tag  =4;
  btn5.tag  =5;
  btn6.tag  =6; 
  btn7.tag  =7;
  btn8.tag  =8;
  btn9.tag  =9;
  btn10.tag =10;

  NSLog(@"End of buttonsTag Method");

}


 //The console output:
 //2012-10-10 14:22:29.308 APP[3691:c07] Beginning of buttonsTag Method
 //2012-10-10 14:22:29.309 APP[3691:c07] End of buttonsTag Method
 //The deference is 14:22:29.309 - 14:22:29.308 = 00:00:00.001
```

Answer (score 1):

For better CPU analysis, you should use Time profiler in XCode Instruments.

Refer http://cocoaforbreakfast.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/time-profiler-when-a-small-change-can-bring-huge-gains/